# Is there a way to input field information by cvs file?

Tags: ms-access, import

I am importing a new database. I am asked to input field information in MS Access manually. Is there a simpler way? For example, import a cvs version field information into the following

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found how to copy structure only for a access database table:

> To copy the table structure, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Right-click the existing table name in the Database Window of the original database and click Copy.
> 2. Close the database Window and open your new database.
> 3. Under Objects, click Tables. Then, right-click the database Window and click Paste.
> 4. Enter a name for the new table, choose Structure Only, and then click OK.

Maybe this helps.

**Source:**

http://www.techrepublic.com/article/copy-an-existing-table-structure-into-a-new-access-database/